How to set different cell properties for different lines of multi-line header in flextable?
How would I/is it even possible to take a multi-header flextable and give different background, text, or other properties to different lines of the header?
For example, say I have this table:
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

# Data
dat <- penguins %>% 
  select(species, island, ends_with("mm")) %>% 
  group_by(species, island) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(
      where(is.numeric), 
      .fns = list(
        avg = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
        sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
    ),
    .groups = "drop") %>% 
  rename_with(~ tolower(gsub("_mm_", "_", .x, fixed = TRUE)))

# Flextable
ft <- dat %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  separate_header() %>% 
  autofit()

ft

Result
But I wanted only the very top part of the header (the columns reading "bill" and "flipper") to have a red background instead of a white background. Is this possible?
I naively expected something like this would work, but the flextable::bg() function's part argument can only take on the value "header", among others, so this returned an error
ft <- bg(ft, bg = 'red', part = 'header 1')

Error in match.arg(part, c("all", "body", "header", "footer"), several.ok = FALSE) : 
  'arg' should be one of “all”, “body”, “header”, “footer”


This should demonstrate how to use selectors (i or j):
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(flextable)

# Data
dat <- penguins %>% 
  select(species, island, ends_with("mm")) %>% 
  group_by(species, island) %>% 
  summarise(
    across(
      where(is.numeric), 
      .fns = list(
        avg = ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
        sd = ~ sd(.x, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
    ),
    .groups = "drop") %>% 
  rename_with(~ tolower(gsub("_mm_", "_", .x, fixed = TRUE)))

# Flextable
ft <- dat %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  separate_header() %>% 
  autofit()

ft <- bg(ft, bg = 'black', part = 'header', i = 1, j = 1:2)
ft <- bg(ft, bg = 'red', part = 'header', i = 1, j = 3:ncol_keys(ft))
ft <- bg(ft, bg = 'yellow', part = 'header', i = 2, j = 3:4)
ft <- bg(ft, bg = 'wheat', part = 'header', i = 2, j = 5:6)
ft <- bg(ft, bg = 'gray', part = 'header', i = 2, j = 7:8)


ft



